# Subtract a specified number of hours from a given date/time to get a new date/time

Tags: vba, excel, date, vb6

I'm trying to figure out how to calculate a date/time by subtracting a given number of hours from a given due date/time, so that I know when I need to start a process step on a product component in order to have it finished in time to ship to the customer.

For example, the product needs to be ready to ship to the customer by 15:00 on September 15, 2017

The final assembly and verification steps, from last to first, are

- Step 15  - requires 12.6 hours to complete
- Step 10  - requires 32.1 hours to complete
- Step 05  - requires 25.9 hours to complete

working backwards

- step 15 would need to be complete by 15:00 on 9/15/2017 to ship to customer
- step 10 would need to be complete by  02:24 on 9/15/2017 to start step 15 on time
- step 05 would need to be complete by 06:18 on 9/13/2017 to start step 10 on time
- All components would need to be ready for assembly by 04:24 on 9/12/2017 to start step 05 on time

I've spent the day searching for an example that would be close enough to what I want and I think I will have to do something with the DateTime function, I'm just not sure what at the moment

Comment: Are the steps always serial, or can some run parrallel?  should we always assum a 24 hour work day.  Seems like a simple sum of the three times being subtracted from the finish date time: `=A1 - (SUM(B1:B3)/24)` where A1 is the ship date and time and B1:B3 is the location of the time it takes for each step.  You can modify the formula to do each line.

Comment: @ScottCraner - In some cases it would be possible to run some of the processes parallel (though this would be a shop floor decision based on machine availability).  In most cases the work day would be 24 hours but there are some occasions (i.e. inventory) where the work day may be cut short by a shift or so

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can subtract n hours from a date by simply subtracting `n/24` from it. You can also use the `TimeSerial` function to subtract hours, minutes and seconds. This example illustrates the two methods, it subtracts 1 hour and a half from the current time using the two methods.

```
Sub substractDates()
  Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date, d3 as Date
  d1 = Now()
  d2 = d1 - TimeSerial(1, 30, 0)
  d3 = d1 - 1.5 / 24
  Debug.Print d1, d2, d3
End Sub
```

p.s. yet a third way is to use `TimeValue("1:30:0")` which is equivalent to `TimeSerial(1, 30, 0)`.

Comment: Implicity types conversion...I would correct it like this: `d1 As Double`, `d1 = CDbl(Now())`, `d3 = CDate(d1 - 1.5 / 24)`

Answer (score 0):

This macro will give you an Idea how to set it up: It can further processed to use user input or take time from a list.

```
Sub test()
Dim dtmstart As Date
Dim steps(2) As Double
Dim duration, hours As Double
dtmstart = "2017/9/15 15:00"
steps(0) = 12.6
steps(1) = 32.1
steps(2) = 25.9

MsgBox "Last step will need to be completed by: " & dtmstart
For Each c In steps
'convert hours to days
hours = c / 24
duration = dtmstart - hours
dtmstart = Application.Text(duration, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm")
MsgBox dtmstart
Next c
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The DateAdd method is used to add to or subtract from a Date object. The first parameter is the interval type. In the code below "h" is for hours and "n" is for minutes. To work backwards, enter your hours and minutes as negative values.

```
Dim dtShipTime As Date
Dim dtStep15Start As Date
Dim dtStep10Start As Date
Dim dtStep05Start As Date

dtShipTime = #9/15/2017 3:00:00 PM#

dtStep15Start = DateAdd("h", -12, dtShipTime)
dtStep15Start = DateAdd("n", -36, dtStep15Start)

dtStep10Start = DateAdd("h", -32, dtStep15Start)
dtStep10Start = DateAdd("n", -6, dtStep10Start)

dtStep05Start = DateAdd("h", -25, dtStep10Start)
dtStep05Start = DateAdd("n", -54, dtStep05Start)
```

Reference
http://www.chennaiiq.com/developers/reference/visual_basic/functions/dateadd.asp